# Functions with the same name

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-10

I'm trying to use a function called `bind()`, this function is included in `WinSock2.h`. However, when I "go to definition" of the function VS leads me to another file.

So, the `bind()` function I'm trying to use is in:

`c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h`

But VS it taking the function from:

`c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional`

How can I "force" VS to use the function I want?

Comment: The bind you got lead to is exclusive to C++

Comment: Did you write `using namespace std`?

Comment: Have you added the path `c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h` in include path of the VS? There must be a setting to provide custom include path in VS.

Comment: Is the second `bind` function in any namespace by chance?

Comment: Stop doing `using namespace std;` and/or change `bind()` to `::bind()`

Comment: Definitely stop `using namespace`. If the *IDE* gets confused, imagine the poor maintenance coder encountering your code in a couple of years...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Changing bind() to ::bind() worked. Thanks!

Comment: @DevSolar that's exactly what's happening to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ header file `<functional>` includes `std::bind` function.

So If u want to use your own bind function, u don't have to write `using namespace std`.

Because VS understands your bind function as `std::bind` of `namespace std`.

[C++ reference of bind function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/?kw=bind) is here.

Comment: Searching in "entire solution" didn't find any `using namespace std`. Still, the problem was related with the namespaces. So using global namespace (`::bind()`) solved my problem. Thks